# SVG Sprite positioning within an input

Tags: css, svg, background, sprite

I have an SVG sprite that contains two icons.

Using the following CSS I am trying to get this sprite image to sit center within the input submit.

```
input[type=submit] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%; // Background to fill container height
    width: 20px;
    background: #FFF url('/-/graphics/search.svg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 200%;
    background-position: 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;           
}
```

The sprite is within this container, like so, but the icon just expands to the size of the input, not to 20px. The height of the grey container is approx 80px.

[image]

Can anyone shed any light on how you can have an SVG sprite positioned within an input like this, set at a certain size?

Here is the SVG code:

```
<svg version="1.1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="30.239px" 
    height="30.239px" 
    viewBox="0 0 60.478 60.478">

     <defs>
        <g id="search">
            <path d="M20.194,3.46c-4.613-4.613-12.121-4.613-16.734,0c-4.612,4.614-4.612,12.121,0,16.735
                c4.108,4.107,10.506,4.547,15.116,1.34c0.097,0.459,0.319,0.897,0.676,1.254l6.718,6.718c0.979,0.977,2.561,0.977,3.535,0
                c0.978-0.978,0.978-2.56,0-3.535l-6.718-6.72c-0.355-0.354-0.794-0.577-1.253-0.674C24.743,13.967,24.303,7.57,20.194,3.46z
                 M18.073,18.074c-3.444,3.444-9.049,3.444-12.492,0c-3.442-3.444-3.442-9.048,0-12.492c3.443-3.443,9.048-3.443,12.492,0
                C21.517,9.026,21.517,14.63,18.073,18.074z"/>
        </g>
     </defs>

    <use x="0" y="0" style="fill: #d94e48" xlink:href="#search" />  
    <use x="30.239" y="0" style="fill: #777" xlink:href="#search" />        

</svg>
```

Comment: I have added the SVG code to the question. I already have a viewbox. Could you explain why I need to change the viewbox dimensions?

Comment: I assumed you didn't given you had the issues you describe and you hadn't shown me the SVG code. Never was that good at mind reading.